# How to enable mcrypt php extension on xampp linux

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, mcrypt

I have installed xampp on my ubuntu machine through the installer having php version 7.2.4

Recently I need to enable Mcrypt PHP extension but I did not find it on php.ini file.

I have tried to modify php.ini following ways but it is not working

`extension=mcrypt`

[image]

What would be the easiest way to enable the mcrypt php extesion on xampp linux?

Comment: mcrypt has been removed from PHP because it is abandonware. You should be using opensll or libsodium

Comment: @JohnConde but i need to configure it as i have a project where it has dependencies and without it i could not proceed. any suggestion please?

Comment: Use the normal ubuntu packages instead of installing a third party distribution like xampp.

Comment: @arkascha as i have already a setup using xampp where other projects are running. I need to configure it on xampp linux version

Comment: mcrypt has been removed from PHP 7.2 onwards - your only chance to get it back, is downgrading PHP to less than 7.2 or use it from the PECL repository, where it has been moved to...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz what could be the way i could install mcrypt with minimum changes? please advice

Comment: @Md.ZiyedUddin I have never done that before. And I don't do decisions for you. My advise: Set up a second system with PHP 7.1, copy your project to it and test thoroughly. Once you're confident everything is ok, change your live system. And then review your project for PHP > 7.1 (without mcrypt). Alas, that will probably be ALOT of changes, but eventually you'd have to do it (if you don't want to let your project decompose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed a PHP 7.0 version of xampp linux separately and found mcrypt available there but it is not available from PHP 7.1.

Its working well now with PHP 7.0 version without any prior change